# Memory exhaust error

Tags: linux, memory

I am getting memory related error when I try to split a big file into 8GB files.

```
# split -C 8000000000 r_mini_20120503.txt  
split: memory exhausted
```

I am however able to create 4GB files using the same command. Is there any way to increase memory for this purpose?

Comment: I doubt it's a memory issue, more likely the version of 'split' you are using doesn't support large files. Grab the src and recompile with '-D FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' (this will work on recent 32bit as well as 64bit)

Comment: That's not the question though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe `split` is the somewhat wrong tool for this task. You can try it with `dd` (untested):

```
infile=r_mini_20120503.txt
filesize=1234567890 # manual set
skip=0
chunk=8000000000
bs=1000000000
count=8
part=1

while [ $skip -lt $filesize ] ; do
    dd if=$infile of=$infile.$part bs=$bs count=$count skip=$skip
    skip=[[ $skip + $chunk ]]
    part=[[ $part + 1 ]]
done
```

As I wrote, untested.

Comment: This is interesting, but deeply, deeply scary.

Comment: Why is that scary?

Comment: I find dd scary.

Comment: especially the "untested" part along with `dd` is scary :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you're trying to use more memory than is on your system.
You could have a go at doing this in Single User mode, so there's less services, and other stuff (like X and GDM) running.

To do that, run `telinit 1`

OR.. 
Install more RAM.  It's cheap.

Answer (score 0):

How much RAM is in your box? You could add some more swap to your system for the time being, but that's going to be dog slow :P